# Zend Framework 2 Db getColumns

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

What exactly is 'getColumns' supposed to return? If I retrieve a table using the abstract interface, it appears the only way I can get the column names is using the Metadata class which my IDE is saying is deprecated. Yet despite hours of searching, I can't seem to find any information on what is replacing it's functionality.
I thought it might be 'getColumns' in the table gateway, but I always get an empty set any time I call it on a defined table.

Comment: To which `getColumns` method are you referring to? `Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway` or `Zend\Db\Metadata` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RDBMS Metadata documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-db/metadata/)

The class `Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata` is actually deprecated, but the functionnality is still there. If you look inside the class, you'll find this note:

```php
/**
 * @deprecated Use Zend\Db\Metadata\Source\Factory::createSourceFromAdapter($adapter)
 */
class Metadata implements MetadataInterface
{
   ...
}
```

So, instead to instantiate directly the `Metadata` class, you'll have to use the factory:

```php
// This is deprecated
// $metadata = new \Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata($adapter);

// This is the correct way to obtain the metadata 
$metadata = \Zend\Db\Metadata\Source\Factory::createSourceFromAdapter($adapter);

// get the table names
$tableNames = $metadata->getTableNames();

foreach ($metadata->getTableNames() as $tableName) {
    echo 'In Table ' . $tableName . PHP_EOL;

    $table = $metadata->getTable($tableName);

    echo '    With columns: ' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($table->getColumns() as $column) {
        echo '        ' . $column->getName()
        . ' -> ' . $column->getDataType()
        . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was essentially what I was looking for!